почему не работает mediaPlayer
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        val btn :Button = findViewById(R.id.playButton)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("R.raw.salo")
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }


    }
}


Потому что id в кавычках - это строка, а в строке плеер ждёт путь к файлу. Читайте документацию и используйте подходящие методы с соответствующими аргументами

@woesss, ответы - в ответы.
